# Get index or key given the value in java Map

Tags: java, dictionary

Given the value, I need to get the index or key which this value belongs in a Map without the need to iterate it. I'm using java.

Thanks

Comment: @PradeepSimha Nothing so far. Im still researching. I tried iterating but it takes quite some time. Im just asking if there's an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava has a [BiMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap), which is a bidirectional map (each key and each value are unique).

If you don't waht to use an external library, you only have 2 options:

- use a plain `HashMap` and you will need to iterate over the keys
- use 2 hashmaps, one relating keys to values, and one relating values to keys (which in essence is what a bidirectional map does).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a BidiMap from commons-collections:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some kind of `BidirectionalMap`. For example this one: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't without iterating.

Also, the value could belong to *multiple* keys, so your question is somewhat moot.

---

If there was a one-to-one relationship between the keys/values, you could do it by having two maps - one for each direction of the relationship - and looking up the value as a key of the second (reverse) map.